# Java stopped working in Firefox. Works in IE

Tags: java, firefox

Some Java applications recently stopped working in Firefox.  I believe there was a recent upgrade to Firefox (it is now on 38.0.1), and this may have brought about the issue.  My Java version and settings did not change, so I think that it must have been a silent upgrade.  Also, the same applications still work in Internet Explorer, so I know that Java itself is still working.

Now, even if I go to the "Verify Java Version" page on java.com through Firefox, I only get a grey box after I click Agree and Continue.

When this issue first came up, I had both Java 6R27 and Java 7R11.  I've tried upgrading Java to the latest version 8, but even with that as the only installed Java version, I am not able to run the Verify Java or my other application.

When I launch my main application that needs Java, I get "ClassNotFoundException" for "PasswordDialog.class."  How can I troubleshoot why this does not work in Firefox while it does work in Internet Explorer?

Comment: This is not an issue. Firefox has dropped support for NPAPI, which means it doesn't support for Applets by default.

Comment: I would try to get away from applets; they aren't supported in Microsoft Edge.

Comment: How can I get Firefox to support it again?

Comment: I got it working by downgrading Firefox to 37.0.2

Comment: Same here, but it works for offline applets.

Answer (score 0):

Download the jxpiinstall installation not the JDK one.
The best way to install Java and run FireFox is to get the JRE running not the JDK, I found out that installing each on separate folders did the trick for me.
So I have my JDK in : C:\jdk1.8.0_60
And my JRE in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_60
First, you need to remove java from your pc, uninstall FF and reinstall FF then Java